# can you explain why variable name is not showing me undefined?

Tags: javascript

```html
<script>
  var name;
  var marks;
  var pass_status=true;
  document.writeln("name are:"+name);
  document.writeln("pass status is:"+pass_status);
  document.writeln("marks are:"+marks);
</script>
```

Can you explain why variable `name` is not showing me undefined?

Comment: Which variable? Explain exactly what is happening

Comment: @as.if.i.code `name`

Answer (score 3):

name is global variable ,just try :

```
console.log(window);
```

you will see that it has `name` property.that's why it is not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a `var` variable outside of any function, it’s assigned to the global object, which means `window` inside the browser. Since `name` is a standard property of `window` it already exists before your code snippet is executed. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

So in your case calling `name` equals to `window.name` which is an empty string by default. To avoid such side effects it is recommended to use ES6 `let/const` variable declaration.

```js
let name;
console.log(name);
```

The result will be `undefined` since `name` in this case is not attached to a global object.